Document not defined error with Flowbite and Angular 18 SSR
first time posting on stack overflow and very junior dev, sorry if there's some mistake in the way to present the issue.
I'm trying to use Flowbite library with Angular 18 SSR.
flowbite.service.ts :
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FlowbiteService {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {}

  loadFlowbite(callback: (flowbite: any) => void) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      import('flowbite').then((flowbite) => {
        callback(flowbite);
      });
    }
  }
}


app.components.ts :
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'dashboard-simplon';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    initFlowbite();
  }
}

one of the component i'm trying to use flowbite in :
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FlowbiteService } from '../../../../services/flowbite.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-progress-bar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './dashboard-progress-bar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dashboard-progress-bar.component.scss',
  providers: [FlowbiteService],
})
export class DashboardProgressBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title = 'test';

  constructor(private flowbiteService: FlowbiteService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.flowbiteService.loadFlowbite((flowbite) => {
      // Your custom code here
      console.log('Flowbite loaded', flowbite);
    });
  }
}

I've followed the installation steps here : https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/angular/
As well as this github issue : https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/800 to no success.
I know the issue comes from the fact that Flowbite tries to use document from the DOM API, but I don't understand what can be done to fix the issue.

The solution to your issue is to run flowbite only on the browser.
The recommended way is to use afterNextRender() which will its callback only on the browser:
export class DashboardProgressBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title = 'test';

  constructor(private flowbiteService: FlowbiteService) {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      // this only runs in the browser
      this.flowbiteService.loadFlowbite((flowbite) => {
        console.log('Flowbite loaded', flowbite);
      });
    });
  }
}

Also depending on your needs you could simply disable SSR.

If you're encountering the "document is not defined" error even after installing Flowbite, here’s what you can do:
Check angular.json:
Ensure Tailwind CSS and Flowbite are properly configured in your angular.json file.
Example configuration -
Check to Tailwind is Configured Correctly. After run ng serve.
Since I am new to this, if I have said something wrong or if anyone can explain my mistake, I will humbly accept it. Thank you.

The suggestion to check the angular.json file for Flowbite and Tailwind configuration is a good step for styling, but it doesn’t solve the main issue causing the "document is not defined" error. This error happens because Flowbite tries to access the DOM (e.g., document.querySelector), which isn’t available during SSR (Server-Side Rendering).
